# Wait for LocationClient callback

Tags: java, android, callback

I am trying to write simple method to get location via Google Play Services. Something like this (yeah, it probably has some other problems..):

```
Location getLastLocation() {
    final Location location = new Location("");
    locationClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(final Bundle connectionHint) {
            location.set(locationClient.getLastLocation());
            locationClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
            locationClient.disconnect();
        }

        @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {};
        });
    if (!locationClient.isConnecting() || !locationClient.isConnected()) {
        locationClient.connect();
    }
    return location;
}
```

obviously, it will return empty `Location`. So, how can I make it wait for the callback to finish? Of course, without blocking main thread....

Comment: You can't. If you want to have the location synchronously, you'll have to wait for it. The only possibility I see is to fetch it from time to time in a thread (think of a service) and cache it, so you have a Location instantly when you ask for it.

Comment: You could probably make an Async Task run or show a progress Dialog...but it seems rather pointless. Why not just wait for the Location, or just use getLastKnownLocation until the new location comes in

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625967/java-equivalent-of-nets-manualresetevent-and-waithandle) might be helpful