# Does Java have a native AutoResetEvent equivalent?

Tags: java, synchronization, autoresetevent

[There's a good equivalent written by a StackOverflow contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625967/java-equivalent-of-nets-manualresetevent-and-waithandle). But that's 10 years old. Has Java come up with an equivalent to [AutoResentEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.autoresetevent?view=netcore-3.1) in the Java runtime?

We're on Java 8.

Comment: Are you looking for `CyclicBarrier`? Your question fails to explain what `AutoResetEvent` is.

Comment: Java's purpose is not to duplicate the *exact same* classes as C#, and vice-versa. Based on the description it doesn't seem like there's a similar class (`java.util.concurrent` doesn't get that much new content), so you might want to approach this with what you want to achieve instead of what class you'd use if you were writing C#.